# How to update views with an asynchronous events in a service or factory in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that receives asynchronous events (from socket.io) and I want to update the views when a new event is triggered. As the view is not binded to the service, I can't update the view. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: It's not a good, but you can use $rootScope.$broadcast. But better way collect you events and watch size of collection $scope.$watchColection(function() { return Service.events }, onEventHendler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 5 ways to achieve that:

**Option 1**: From the controller, pass the $rootScope in the service or factory. Then when    the event is triggered, use the function $rootScope.apply(). This    will update the view. For instance, in your controller:

```
angular.module('Project', ['Messages']).controller('MyCtrl', function(Messages){
    // here we pass the $rootScope (or $scope if you want) to the service
    MyService.init($rootScope); 
}

angular.module('Project.factory', []).factory('Messages', function(){
    var Messages = {};
    var scope;
    Messages.init = function(scope_ctrl){ 
        scope = scope_ctrl;             
    }
    return Messages;
}
```

In your asynchronous function being fired within your service/factory, call scope.apply():

```
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    scope.apply();
})
```

---

**Option 2**: Use a callback. Define a callback function in the controller:

```
  angular.module('Project', ['Messages']).controller('MyCtrl', function(Messages){

    // Call function
    var callback = function(){
       $scope.$apply()
    }
    // here we pass the $rootScope (or $scope if you want) to the service
    MyService.init(callback); 
}

angular.module('Project.factory', []).factory('Messages', function(){
    var Messages = {};
    var callback;
    Messages.init = function(callback_ctrl){ 
        callback = callback_ctrl;             
    }
    return Messages;
}
```

In your asynchronous function being fired within your service/factory, call the function callback, which will then execute the code as defined in the controller:

```
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    callback(); 
})
```

---

**Option 3**: In your service, update the element Id in the view.

```
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    var element = angular.element($('#MyElementWithController'));
    element.scope().$apply();
})
```

I personnaly don't like this option because you need to manage the element from your service, so it's not good for code re-usability.

---

**Option 4**: Use $q (the best approach)
$q is wired up with the Angular digest cycle so no need to do anything with $apply().

In your asynchronous function being fired withing your service/factory, use $q like this:

```
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    // Function being fired on the asyncrhonous event
    return doSomething();
})
```

Where:

```
function doSomething(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

** Do not forget to include the parameter $q in your service. Like:

```
angular.module('Project.factory', []).factory('Messages', function($q)
{

}
```

---

**Option 5**: Use broadcast:

```
angular.module('Project.factory', []).factory('Messages', function($broadcast){
    socket.on('update', function(data) {
        $broadcast("new message", data);
    })
}
```

In the controller:

```
$on("new message", function(new_messages){
    // here the view will update with new messages
    $scope.messages = new_messages; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a natural pattern for Angular.

Your views should be bound to controllers. Those controllers can have the your service injected into them.

```
YourService.$inject = ['socket'];
function YourService(socket) {
    this._subscribers = [];

    var self = this;

    socket.on('update', function(data) {
        this.updateSubscribers(data);
    })
}

YourService.prototype.subscribe = function(callback) {
    this.subscribers.push(callback);
}

YourService.prototype.updateSubscribers = function(data) {
    this.subscribers.forEach(function(subscriber) {
        subscriber(data);
    }) 
}

angular.module('yourModule').service('yourService', yourService);
```

This assumes your socket is registered in the `injector` as `socket`.

Then in your controllers you can inject this service and subscribe to asynchronous updates. Be sure to call `$scope.apply()` in the controller to trigger the update in `Angular`.

```
 YourController.$inject = ['yourService', '$scope'];
 function YourController(yourService, $scope) {

      this.data;

      var self = this;

      yourService.subscribe(function(data) {
          self.data = data;
          $scope.$apply();
      });
 }
```

If in `ngRouter` or `uiRouter` this controller is configured as `YourController as vm`:

```
<div>{{ vm.data }}</div>
```

Now on any `async` update this view will update.